# select option - how to use change event to show news in selected category

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have 2 tables like that:

- Category {categoryId, categoryName}
- News {newsId, newsTitle, categoryId}

In my asp.net mvc project, I have a View:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
        function ()
        {
            $("#slCategory").change(
                function ()
                {
                    var value = $(this).val();
                    if (value == "All")
                        location.href = "GetAllByCategory";
                    else
                        location.href = "GetAllByCategory/?category=" + value;
                }
            );
        }
    );
</script>

<h2>Get All By Category</h2>

Select Category
<select name="slCategory" id="slCategory">    
    <option value="All">All</option>
    <option value="1">Sport</option>
    <option value="2">Social</option>
    <option value="3">Economy</option>
</select>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{ 
    <p>@item.newsTitle</p>
}
```

It's not work!

How to use change event to show news in selected category?

Comment: Have U debugged in browser, is that function called?

Comment: function was fine when first called, but in the second, it's not work because js file location not found, do you have solution for that? thanks

Comment: This is strange how can a function be called first time and not on the second occassion ,

Comment: first time: ../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js and second time: ../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js can not be found because page location is changed (ex: GetAllByCategory/?category=2)

Comment: Have u tried @Jaimin answer

Comment: I am trying, thank u!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
        function ()
        {
            $("#slCategory").change(
                function ()
                {
                    var value =  $("#slCategory").val();
                    if (value == "All")

                      window.location.href = '@Url.Action( "GetAllByCategory", "YourController")'
                    else

                      window.location.href = '@Url.Action( "GetAllByCategory", "YourController")?category'+ value ;
                }
            );
        }
    );
</script>
```

Comment: jquery library location is changed in the second time, what solution?

Comment: @LittleMan Sorry i don't understand `jquery library location is changed in the second time`. Please explain more or show your `window.location.href`.

Comment: Sorry, my English is not good. First: my url is localhost/GetAllByCategory. When I change value in select option, my url is localhost/GetAllByCategory/?category=2 and the location of file jquery-1.7.1.min.js is changed, can you help me fix that problem, thanks

Comment: @LittleMan where is the controller name if you are calling action in this url localhost/GetAllByCategory/?category=2

Comment: @LittleMan than you have to use `Ajax` function.

Comment: HomeController,  localhost/Home/GetAllByCategory, Is that ok if I don't use Ajax

Comment: @LittleMan Yes it's ok.

Comment: @LittleMan  if you use this ' window.location.href' then it's redirect you to another page and if you want to show `news` same page then you have to use 'Ajax'. otherwise  it's ok.

Comment: @LittleMan so you got your ans.

Comment: @LittleMan If you think my ans is right then `Accept ans` so anybody has same problem then this can be helpful.